# TinyMCE plugin: show a tooltip on an element

Tags: tinymce

is it possible to show a tooltip with HTML content on an element in the TinyMCE editor? I am creating a plugin that has to annotate some words with additional content and I want to show these tooltips when hovering the relevant words. The problem is that the TinyMCE documentation seems to be very bad.

Something like this:

```
editor.on("click", function(e) {
    editor.showTooltipOnElement(e.target, "<p>Hello, I am a tooltip");
});
```

I am not using the default HTML title attribute, because I want to include custom HTML content into the tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I solved this myself, kind of hacky though. I use the TinyMCE context menu function to create a context menu on the selected element and then replace the contents of the context menu with my custom HTML. Benefit is that clicking anywhere within the window also hides the menu again.

```
editor.on("click", function(e) {
    var menu = new tinymce.ui.Menu({
        items: [{
            text: "Some tooltip text"
        }],
        context: "contextmenu",
        onhide: function() { menu.remove(); }
    });

    menu.renderTo(document.body);
    menu.$el.html(htmlGenerator());

    var pos = tinymce.DOM.getPos(editor.getContentAreaContainer());
    var targetPos = editor.dom.getPos(target);
    var root = editor.dom.getRoot();

    if(root.nodeName === "BODY") {
        targetPos.x -= root.ownerDocument.documentElement.scrollLeft || root.scrollLeft;
        targetPos.y -= root.ownerDocument.documentElement.scrollTop || root.scrollTop;
    } else {
        targetPos.x -= root.scrollLeft;
        targetPos.y -= root.scrollTop;
    }

    pos.x += targetPos.x;
    pos.y += targetPos.y;

    menu.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y + target.offsetHeight + 5);
    menu.$el.removeClass("mce-container");
});
```

Comment: This is great example, just note that to make it a tooltip use: var tooltip = new tinymce.ui.Tooltip({ text: "some tooltip" });

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it with `tooltip` on the button properties:

```js
tinymce.init({ 
...other 
    setup: function(editor)
    {
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
            type: 'menubutton',
            tooltip: "My custom button",
            icon: 'myicon',
            menu: [
                {
                    text: 'Action_A',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;{{A}}&nbsp;');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Action_B',
                    onclick: function() {
                        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;{{B}}&nbsp;');
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    }
..other 
});
```

[Basic setup](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/basic-setup/)

[More info](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The issue with tooltip is that if assigned to element inside TinyMCE content it **will not scroll**.
Unless you move the tooltip also within TinyMCE content and use ".mce-offscreen-selection" wrapper.
Still lots of work and possible bugs to deal with.

The easiest solution is something like this:

```
<span data-mytooltip="My Tooltip">This</span> is content in TinyMCE
```

And then put CSS styling:

```
.span[data-mytooltip]{ position:relative; }
.span[data-mytooltip]:before{
      content:attr(data-mytooltip);
      position:absolute;
      top:-15px;background:#ffffcc;color:#000;
  }
```

You get the idea.